# How much compatibility do the DB engines have at the SQL level?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, firebird

Let's say I wanted to have an application that could easily switch the DB at the back-end.
I'm mostly thinking of SQL Server as the primary back-end, but with the flexibility to go another DB engine.  Firebird and PostGreSQL seem to have (from my brief wikipedia excursion) the most in common w/ SQL Server (plus they are free).

How similar would the DB setup, access, queries, etc.. be for Firebird, PostGreSQL and MS SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked on one project where it was an absolute requirement to support many databases, including at least Access, SQL Server and Oracle.

So I know that it can be done. Mostly DML (SELECT,UPDATE,INSERT...) is the same and certainly we didn't have huge problems making it work across all of the databases - just occasional annoyances. MySQL was the exception at that time as it simply wasn't capable enough.

We found most differences in the DDL, but with the right architecture (which we had), it wasn't difficult to fix this.

The only thing that caused us a problem was generating unique id's - autoincrement is non-standard. Fortuantely in a database of around 40 tables there were only a few places where unique ID's were need (good DB design). In the end we generate the unique ID in code, and handle any clashes (everything in transactions).

It did make things easier because we had avoided using autoincrement for ID fields, it's harder to think of unique keys - but better in the long run.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, SQL varies widely across providers. It's almost impossible to write all but the most trivial SQL to run on a number of RDBMS - and then you're into lowest common denominator territory. Far better to use an abstraction layer to handle at least the connection to the database (inc. access, sending queries), and either an ORM to handle the SQL itself or per-provider SQL.

If you want to look into how they vary - good examples are auto-incrementing ids and obtaining the ID of the last inserted record.

Answer (score 1):

Well, CRUD stuff should be the same everywhere, but if you build anything complex, you'll probably want to use triggers and stored procedures and that's where compatibility becomes low. Writing a DBMS-agnostic application usually means moving most of the business logic outside of database, so having a 3-tier application is, IMHO, a must in such case.

Alternatively, you could use some wrapper library that works like abstraction layer, but I'm yet to see one that is able to do the job correctly over a range of DBMS-es. Of course, that is also dependent on the programming language you use.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by the other answers, DBMS vary wildly once you go beyond basic SELECT/INSERT stuff (and sometimes even there).

We also have to maintain compatibiliy across several DBMS. In my opinion the best approach is usually to use some kind of compatibility layer. We have an in-house DB abstraction library, but there are several tools available.

In particular, it might pay to look at popular ORMs (Hibernate, nHibernate etc.). They usually offer DB-independence as a kind of side effect. At least Hibernate also has a special query language that will automatically be translated to SQL for the DBMS you are using.